# Programmatically set Design Exceptions

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise, configuration, setup-script, mobile

As per the deployment policy, I need to programatically set design exception rules in admin for the mobile theme. I noticed on core_config_data, the value looked like:

`a:1:{s:18:"_1380154833505_505";a:2:{s:6:"regexp";s:111:"iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini";s:5:"value";s:6:"mobile";}}`

Which makes it quite a headache to figure out how to write a setup/installation script for it. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The value represents this array serialized.

```
array (
  '_1380154833505_505' => 
  array (
    'regexp' => 'iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini',
    'value' => 'mobile',
  ),
)
```

I assume that what throws you off is this key. `_1380154833505_505`.
This can be about anything, but keep the consistency you should generate this key like this:

```
$now = microtime (true);
$parts = explode('.', $now);
$key = '_'.$parts[0].'_'.substr($parts[1], 0, 3);
```

When adding the values from the admin, the key is generated by javascript like this:

```
'_' + d.getTime() + '_' + d.getMilliseconds()
```

see file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/form/field/array.phtml`.

the php code above should simulate the same thing.